# Dojo not working for me

Tags: javascript, dojo

I can't get my dojo working. I've tried everything.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4/dojo/dojo.xd.js">


    dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
    console.log("page ready, can modify DOM anytime after this");

});
</script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Error message? Try Firebug? Are you just not seeing the console output?

Comment: Yes, not seeing any console output. No error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take your code and put it in another script tag after the dojo script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.4/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
    console.log("page ready, can modify DOM anytime after this");
});
</script>
```

A script tag with an `src` attribute cannot also contain code, unless you use a [John Resig-like hack](http://ejohn.org/blog/degrading-script-tags/).

Comment: Thanks, but where does the output from console.log go?

Comment: In your example, it doesn't ever actually get called ... the browser just ignores it completely.

Comment: Yes, I know. But with firebug, I use console.debug to get output to the console. Where does console.log go?

Comment: @pfdevil -- the same place :-)